# Why this not working nothing to explain more?

Tags: node.js

When I open two tabs in session after logout in one tab when I try to change data of another tab without reload page at a time redirect not working console shows the message and after that API call.

```
app.use(function(request, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("index.html")
        res.redirect("/");
        //res.end ();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but don't understand the english in your question.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the logout?